# Customize ad look and feel admob flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, ads

I am planning to monetize my flutter using ads.
I would also like to use `AdMob`.

The only drawback is that i have to show the `AdChoices` and the `Ad Attribution`.

It's definitely not beautiful in UI, so i wonder is that `AdMob` that require such thing or should i use another Ad network if i want to show "beautiful" ads ?

Is there any other way to still show ads but without these items in the UI ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is absolutely required to show both `AdChoices` logo and `AD` label by AdMob, and it is legally required in a lot of countries for all Ads networks.

I found out the best choice is using [Native Ads](https://admob.google.com/home/resources/native-ads-playbook/) to make the ad feels more like your app and still show the required labels. here are some exampels:

[image: ad1]

[image: ad2]

[image: ad3]

Comment: Thanks for the examples and confirmation.